# Jquery Simple datepicker not working on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, datepicker

I'm having a little trouble with the JQuery date picker. The datepicker seems to default to December 14, so if I enter a date say in august 15 the date picker wil display December 14. If I select the previous month then the next month again it will go to December 14 rather than August 15. Its as if July 15 was a cut off point and it just loops back to Dec 14. Only occurs in IE8, all other browsers work as expected. Tried some googling but no joy. Anyone any ideas? Feedback is much appreciated.

```
    $(function() {
  var sDtTo = $("#searchDateTimeTo");
  var sDtFrom = $("#searchDateTimeFrom");
  var sform = $('#search-form');

  sDtTo.appendDtpicker({
    'current': '',
    'closeOnSelected': 'true'
  });

  sDtTo.val('');

  sDtFrom.appendDtpicker({
    'current': '',
    'closeOnSelected': 'true'
  });
  sDtFrom.val('');

  sform.tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]'
  });
```

Thanks

Marty

Comment: Post your code please. Also, what versions of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: Please show us the markup around your datepicker, and also the javascript code if you initialize the datpicker from your JS

Comment: The datepicker used is - simpledatetimepicker/1.12.0/jquery.simple-dtpicker.js
https://plugins.jquery.com/simple-dtpicker/